# jSoup - How to get elements with background style (inline CSS)?

Tags: regex, jsoup, railo, cfml

I'm building an app in Railo, which uses the jSoup .jar library. It all works really well in my CFML language.

Anyhow, I can grab every element with a "style" attribute doing:

```
<cfset variables.mySelection = variables.myDocument.select("*[style]") />
```

But this returns an array which contains elements that sometimes do not have a "background" or "background-image" style on them. As an example, the HTML might looks like so:

```
<p style="color: red;">I should not be selected</p>
<p style="background: green">I **should** be selected</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">I should not be selected</p>
<p style="background-image: url("/path/to/image.jpg");">I **should** be selected</p>
```

So I can get these elements above, but I don't want the 1st and 3rd in my array, as they don't have a background style...do you know how I can only grab and work with these?

Please note, I'm **not** after a COMPUTATED style, or anything that complicated, I'm just wondering if I can filter based on the properties of an inline CSS style. Perhaps some regex after the fact? I'm open to ideas!

I tried messing with `:contains(background)` as a key word, but I wasn't sure if that was the correct path?

Many thanks for your help.
Michael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
variables.myDocument.select("*[style*='background']")
```

As [`*=`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) is the standard selector to match a substring in the attribute content.

Comment: Thanks, that looks logical. Can't try it now but I'll be back in the next few hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
Elements els = doc.select(div[style*=dashed]);
```

Or

```
Elements elements = doc1.select("span[style*=font-weight:bold]");
```